# Hide some controls in MDI parent if a child being re-sized

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I want to hide some of my controls in my MDI Parent if a child is being maximized or minimized.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This question is a little general, what are the child controls in your MDI Parent? why do you need such controls while MDI Parent is mainly used to contain child MDI forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
//Form parent
public frmMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pnlHide = panel1;
        }

public static Panel pnlHide= new Panel();


//Form Child
private void frmChiled_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                frmMenu.pnlHide.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                frmMenu.pnlHide.Show();
            }
        }
```